# 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, 500-error

Getting a 500 error, probably caused by an error in my PHP script. For some reason when I have an error it doesn't output it, it just sends me a 500 error. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

The error is going into your log file, but not printed to the server error displayed. This is intentional, because it prevents possibly-sensitive information from being exposed to attackers. (Pathname information, database schemas, possibly something exploitable about the bug that caused the error itself....)

You can either just look at the php error log (probably near wherever your system puts its web server logs), or else you can edit `/etc/php.ini` to read `display_errors = On` instead of Off. Unless this is a protected development system, I suggest the former.

Comment: I did that already, it's still not displaying them.

Comment: In that case, can you provide a whole lot more information, please? What's your OS and web server, what PHP version, what you see in the error logs, what other things you've tried....

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.0.63
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
PHP 5.2.9

Comment: What do you see in the httpd error log? (Usually `/var/log/httpd/error_log`)

Comment: It's been so long since I ran the default config that I forget, but I think you should at least see some startup/shutdown messages in there. That suggests your host is configured to log elsewhere.

Comment: ahah. found the logs using `locate error_logs`, premature end of script headers.

Comment: Awesome. Then the only question is why `display_errors = On` isn't working. (You restarted Apache after making that change, right? Just checking....)

Comment: They were already on when I checked the php.ini. Also, is premature end of script headers a php error anyway? I ran the script locally via the CLI, and it worked fine